# Pandas add space between characters if needed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['One[P]','Two [N]'],
})

df
    A
0   One[P]
1   Two [N]
```

I'd like to add a space before the open bracket ('[') if one does not exist (for a very tall column).

The desired result is:

```
    A
0   One [P]
1   Two [N]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use:

```
df.loc[~df.A.str.contains(r' \['), 'A'] = df.A.str.replace('[',' [')
print df
         A
0  One [P]
1  Two [N]
```

Answer (score 3):

alternatively, you can use RegEx's:

```
In [138]: df.A = df.A.replace(r'([^\s])\[', r'\1 [', regex=True)

In [139]: df
Out[139]:
         A
0  One [P]
1  Two [N]
```

Comment: Maybe you think `df.A.replace(r'([^\s])\[', ' [', regex=True)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but then i would loose one character. Frankly speaking i would prefer your solution ;)

Comment: No problem. alternativly you can use `str.replace` - `df.A.str.replace('([^\s])\[', r'\1 [')`